# SonarQube 4.4 upgrade can not show test coverage on dashboard

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I upgraded my sonarqube from 4.1 to 4.4. as in the latest java plugin 2.4 you don't need to have a JaCoCo plugin. I have deleted the jacoco plugin, but now i can not see Tes coverage on sonar dashboard - it's blank. We use bamboo for CI tool and run sonar build from Bamboo. we run below maven command from bamboo build .

```
clean verify -Psonar sonar:sonar -U -fae -Dsonar.forceAnalysis=true
```

Answer (score 3):

With latest versions of the SQ Java plugin, tests are no longer automatically executed. They must be executed prior to the SonarQube analysis and configured so that they produce reports that can be read by the SQ Java plugin.

Everything is explained on the [Code Coverage by Unit Tests for Java Project](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) documentation page.

Comment: @DanTuffery Thanks for the notification => fixed!